# Jquery .on("click") function is only firing once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I noticed a lot of similar questions here but their solutions didn't seem to work. The click event that I've attached to a button element is only firing once. Any ideas?

My HTML

```
<p id="randomCatchphrase">Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die.</p>
<p id="catch"><button class="catchbutton">Catchphrase me!</button></p>
```

My JS

```
$(function() {
    var catchphraseArray = [
        "Good morning, Vietnam!",
        "Khaaaaan!",
        "Bueller...Bueller...Bueller?",
        "Alrighty then!",
        "I know kung fu.",
        "YOU SHALL NOT PASS!",
        "You can't handle the truth!"
    ];

    function getRandomArrayElement(myArray) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
        return myArray[randomNumber];
    }
    var randomPhrase = getRandomArrayElement(catchphraseArray);

    $("#catch").on("click", ".catchbutton", function() {
        $("#randomCatchphrase").text(randomPhrase)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `click` event do fire multiple time, but did't see it because the value of `randomPhrase` is not change *(have value for first declaration)*, you need to call the function inside `click` handler to update those value anytime the button was pressed like so :

```
$("#catch").on("click", ".catchbutton", function() {
  // here the value will updated anytime when button was clicked
  var randomPhrase = getRandomArrayElement(catchphraseArray);
  $("#randomCatchphrase").text(randomPhrase);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`randomPhrase` is not calling `getRandomArrayElement` , but returning single call to `getRandomArrayElement` saved as variable `randomPhrase`

```
$("#catch").on("click", ".catchbutton", function(){
  $("#randomCatchphrase").text(getRandomArrayElement(catchphraseArray);
});
```